# I can't delete last element from array list in Java

Tags: java, arrays

My program contains 3 classes
Student , Aplt and Aplt3 classes

---

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Student {

    String name;
    int mark;

    Student(String name, int mark) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mark = mark;
    }
}
```

### student class with constructor

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.TextFiEld;
import java.awt.event.ActioNevent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Aplt extends Applet {

    TextField tf[] = new TextField[2];
    Student prs[] = new Student[0];
    ActionListener ins;

    public void init() {
        tf[0] = new TextField("name?", 10);
        tf[1] = new TextField("mark", 5);
        add(tf[0]);
        add(tf[1]);
        tf[1].addActionListener(ins = new Ins());
    }

    class Ins implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String n = tf[0].getText();
            int nt = Integer.parseInt(tf[1].getText());
            Student help[] = new Student[prs.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(prs, 0, help, 0, prs.length);
            help[help.length - 1] = new Student(n, nt);
            prs = help;
            tf[0].setText("next name");
            tf[1].setText("next mark");
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < prs.length; i++) {
            g.drawString(prs.name, 10, 50 + 12 * i);
            g.drawString(prs.mark + "", 130, 50 + 12 * i);
        }
    }
}
```

### here is aplt class. class lists us given names and marks

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Aplt3 extends Aplt {

    Button b1, b2;

    public void init() {
        super.init();
        b1 = new Button("remove");
        b1.addActionListener(new B1());
        add(b1);
    }

    class B1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < prs.length; i++) {
                Student help[] = new Student[prs.length - 1];
                System.arraycopy(help, 0, help, 0, help.length);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

aplt3 class. Here I want to delete last element of array when I click to remove button, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: You are trying to initialize `help` array inside the loop.. You might want get that out of the loop.. And what is the `prs` here??

Comment: Where is the ARRAYLIST here (title)? You have defined the `help` array inside the loop. How you use it? I think that you want to copy `help` array to `prs` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you use to add a student:

```
Student help[] = new Student[prs.length+1]; 
System.arraycopy(prs, 0, help, 0, prs.length); 
help[help.length-1]= new Student (n,nt); 
prs=help;
```

Just use the same idea to remove one:

```
Student help[] = new Student[prs.length-1]; 
System.arraycopy(prs, 0, help, 0, help.length); 
prs=help;
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks very suspicious to me:

```
for ( i=0 ; i<prs.length; i++) { 
Student help[] = new Student[prs.length-1]; 


System.arraycopy(help, 0, help, 0, help.length); 

}
```

You copy the array help to itself and with the complete size of the array. Moreover you do this in a loop which does not look good. I think that all your looking for is something like this:

```
Student help[] = new Student[prs.length-1]; 
System.arraycopy(prs, 0, help, 0, help.length);
```

and no loop at all. Make sure that prs is not empty, otherwise you will run into problems.

By the way, brackets indicate an "array" not an "ArrayList". An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a Java Collection class.